# Get Data from input as HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, input

`Users` can Upload `Images` and add a `Description`.

But upon entering the Description the `output` on a Page is just the raw Data. Meaning Spaces and Line Breaks are ignored.

How do i set up that the output `respects the Line Breaks` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw data should include line breaks and to show them in HTML you would probably want to use `simple_format` :

```
<%= simple_format(params[:output]) %>
```

Comment: I Collect the inpout via <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "5"} %>, and show it via <%= @pin.description %>. Where does the code go ?

Comment: The code goes where you "show it" : <%= simple_format(@pin.description) %>

Comment: Thanks for my first 15 reputation, now I can finally upvote all the people who have helped me!